# How to change/resize EditText in table layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I just want to resize the edittext so that it matches my texts. When I insert an edittext in a table layout in column 3 it fills the whole space of column 3 and looks big. I want to change the size. How is it possible?
Below is my .xml coding:

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="S"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:text="C"
        android:layout_width="75dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:text="G"/>
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />

<TableRow>
<TextView
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:id="@+id/s1"
    android:text="Medium Text"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:id="@+id/c1"
    android:text="Text"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/g1"
    android:layout_column="3" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: what you want? im little confused, you want to change width or height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem... i tried using wrap_content etc .. but didnt work you have to manually set the height of the EditText....
here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />



</TableRow>
```

Comment: did it work?? let me know if later you come across a way other than manually setting the height :)

Answer (score 1):

Try these,

```
1. Set the "stretchColumn" property of table layout.

2. Set the layout_width of the EditText to "wrap_content".

3. If you want you can fix the size of the EditText by manually setting 
   the layout_width value in dp or dip.
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to specify the column number it picks it itself just place it there if you want edit text to fit the space just strech the column 1&2 in table layout

or you can add linear layout as the table row and assign weight

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/txthwdxml" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```